# How to find list of jar file which is important for some specific jar in intellij

Tags: java

My current project is using old jar with no version number. I need to remove all jar files on which this old jar was dependent. In order to do that i need a list of jar which was important for the old jar.

Answer (score 0):

Try Kirk Knoernschild's [JarAnalyzer](http://www.kirkk.com/main/Main/JarAnalyzer)

> JarAnalyzer is a dependency management utility for jar files. It's primary purpose is to traverse through a directory, parse each of the jar files in that directory, and identify the dependencies between the jar files. The output is an xml file representing the PhysicalDependencies between the jar files.